# How to change the meta keyword and meta description tag for a single article page of a Vbulletin forum?

Tags: seo, vbulletin

Anybody know how to change the meta keyword and meta description tag for a single article page of a Vbulletin forum?

Thanks alot in advance.

B

Answer (score 0):

see: http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/135764-How-do-I-change-meta-tags

```
All CMS pages have their own meta information in the bottom right, of the editing screen (editing sections and editing articles) where it says Metadata Information.
```

p.s.: i think https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ is the better forum for this kind of question, as this is not directly programing related.